# is it possible to turn this dumb-waiter into an elevator?

Tags: safety, home-automation

We recently acquired a house that has an elevator-like mechanism.   The former owners call the thing a "dumb waiter", suggesting that it's not safe for human use.   Although it's roomy enough for a human to stand in, and supposedly has a 300lb capacity, I certainly wouldn't ride in it.  (Amusingly, one of our new neighbors, friend of the former owners, says he's ridden in it; but, he's a retired jockey :-) ).

I'm wondering if there's any possibility of upgrading the thing so that it is safe for human use.   I don't think it'd be possible to install a braking mechanism, like the one on a real elevator.  Absent any other ideas, I think the solution would have to be some sort of redundant suspension mechanism.

This is probably a situation where a picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a few.  The "shaft" is composed of 6x6 timbers at each corner.  The "car" is about 3-feet square and is made of metal; little plastic wheels keep it rolling along the timbers. It's suspended by a small electric motor and a length of 1/4" wire rope.   The overall floor-to-floor height is 18 feet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is going to involve figuring out where the weak points are on that thing and reinforcing them to your satisfaction. This may involve getting a structural engineer involved. And getting a control panel inside the cabin.

Comment: Never mind an elevator, that's not even safe as a dumbwaiter.   It's pretty hopeless but fully enclose the shaft, replace the gates with doors and put interlocks on the doors so they can't be open when the car isn't there ... This won't make it safe but would at least protect bystanders a little.

Comment: Kids can climb on the "fence" in the last photo.

Comment: For an "real" elevator: Dismantle it and ask for quotes for an outdoor elevator according to ASME A17.1

Comment: I think the simple answer is: no.

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised your home insurance company has not made you remove it. It's a huge liability. "Upgrading" would be a matter of remove and replace with something designed for the job, with modern safety features.

Comment: Nice roof though.  Add a floor frame and call it a storage shed.

Comment: @ratchetfreak No structural engineer is going to take responsibility for that thing.

Comment: "I don't think it'd be possible to install a braking mechanism, like the one on a real elevator." That tells me everything I need to know. As others have said, the short answer is going to be 'no'.

Comment: If there is any chance that a child (including a teenager) can figure out how to get in and try to make it work, tear it down now (or at least make it very inoperable).

Comment: If this kind of handiwork was done openly, what else is there?  I'd consider the entire property suspect and would want everything inspected.  That multi-story deck begs to have a structural engineer look at it.  And maybe visit the local municipality to see the last time a permit for anything was pulled.

Comment: In my little dream, someone's job is to sit at the bottom with an ice chest filled with cold brews.  My job is to sit at the top and press a bell when I want them to send me one.

Comment: Looks like fun :-). The suspension system gives me the heeby jeebies just looking at it. I could make that "safe enough" that I would use it. But probably not safe enough that I'd be willing to be responsible for anyone ls doing so. So, probably, no :-(. || I've been by myself in an elevator that went into freefall. Didn't fall far, but very exciting :-). || A full 18' fall with no resistance impacts at 32 feet/second.  Too fast. Suitably strong magnets and aluminum strip could be made to provide acceptable freefall speed limiting. Then there's just the interlocks, child proofing, ...

Comment: "Suitably strong magnets and aluminum strip could be made to provide acceptable freefall speed limiting."  I had to look that up because it sounds so cool.  It looks like the name for that technology is "eddy current braking".  All kinds of interesting applications beyond just elevators.

Comment: I would keep it as a piece of art, while making sure no one can attempt to use it.

Comment: My assumption is that the winch has the 300lb capacity.  Everything else (including the connection of the winch to the frame) is a crapshoot.  That connection to the roof of the "car" terrifies me.

Comment: Don't tell me: the cabin is the ideal size for the former-owner's mother-in-law in her wheelchair.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I assume the insurance company doesn't know about this. "Does the property have an unengineered, rickety elevator constructed out of weathered lumber?" Probably isn't a standard question they ask for new policies. ;)

Comment: @MacGuffin I've seen a demo with a copper pipe and a supply of magnets at the top, in a stairwell.  With practice, it was possible to release a magnet in the pipe, and walk steadily down the stairs just in time to catch it coming out.  I keep meaning to make something similar

Answer (score 35):

No, it can't.  The design presupposes that it is only going to be used for food.  It will not be robust enough or safe enough for people.  Unsafe meaning, collapsing and falling down or just people poking their fingers and arms where they will snap.

Also, note that in NZ, it would have to be certified by a lift specialist.  I suspect this may be true in many parts of the world.

I recommend that you call some companies that make lifts and see if they can fit a solution in the same spot.  The cheaper residential lifts are not that expensive, in NZ anyway.

Comment: Actually the main usage was gardening supplies.

Comment: Gardening supplies can't sue for wrongful death.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Yeah, I actually realize that.   The answerer said "the design presupposes that it is only going to be used for food".   Hence my comment.  Is that ok ?

Comment: And there are no laws regarding injuring or killing gardening supplies. There are plenty for doing so with people.

Comment: @RustyShackleford I suppose a good "benchmark rule" on answering your question would be "Would you put your 4-year old inside it?"

Comment: @RustyShackleford there's nothing special about food or gardening supplies, there is something special about humans. If you put your lawnmower in it and it plummets to its doom and smashes into a million pieces, you just buy a new lawnmower, same if it spills your KFC everywhere. The answer should say it won't be used for people, not that it will only be used for food.

Answer (score 27):

Forget it, this thing is a complete pile of junk.

But don't take my word on it. Ask your insurance company, because I guarantee this thing is news to them.

To qualify as a human-rated elevator it needs to be designed properly from the ground up. And in commercial practicality, that means using an off-the-shelf pre-engineered design, because that is far cheaper than a civil engineer designing an elevator from scratch.  It would be impossible to build an elevator shaft out of 6x6 and have it be safety rated.  Using a winch as a lifting mechanism (and braking mechanism!!!) is also a non-starter

This was a foolish hack design done by the previous homeowner behind the back of his insurance company.  They represented it as a dumbwaiter for cargo only, even though it's obviously built for humans, for liability reasons.

There will be no way to adapt this into a legal elevator.  For your own liability's sake you should either demolish the whole thing, or redesign the car to be 2 feet tall to preclude use by humans, so it truly is a dumbwaiter.

I don't gather that you want a dumbwaiter, but if you did, I would redesign it to have 2 cars moving opposite, so one car is low when  the other is high, and they counterweight each other.  I'd solve the "getting hung up and dropping" problem by having a lower cable also connecting the cars, so one moving up pulls the other down.  The drive mechanism can now be on the bottom.

Comment: Installing permanent shelving with an eye to openings too small for children to fit (2 ft tall car is still too big, IMHO) would be a start on the car. But then there's all the places where it does not adequately exclude body parts or entire persons from being in harms way when it falls.

Comment: Even if redesigned so that the car is not capable of carrying people in any practical way, the bottom section has to be blocked off so a kid couldn't easily climb in and be playing on the bottom when the car comes down with a load of stuff in it. Even an empty car would be dangerous, but the more likely scenario is that somebody at top loads it with trash or whatever and presses the switch to send it down and then heads downstairs to unload at the bottom - with no practical way to see that there was a kid underneath until it is too late.

Comment: This answer comes across as a bit harsh, but I am forced reluctantly to agree. You can imagine that the thing was a project that someone enjoyed both executing and showing off to visitors, even if it was not particularly well-informed from an engineering point of view...

Comment: Starting from this I'd dismantle the cabin, lock the gates, and use the winch with a bucket of some sort for shifting goods.  I'd also fit a keyswitch in the power line so it can't be played with.  Starting from scratch I'd use a block and tackle and muscle power, as I did with my attic to get the floorboards (and camping gear) up there.

Comment: Best part -- this may not even be compliant with ASME A17.1's rules for *dumbwaiters*, so it's probably not even usable *as a dumbwaiter*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, it's in violation of large parts of the ASME A17.1 requirements for dumbwaiters, particularly with regards to enclosures, doors, and safety interlocks.

Comment: @Mark: The term "dumbwaiter" is usually used to refer to a device that may be operated by someone who doesn't have a clear view of the entire range of travel, and/or that can operate without continuous input from an operator.  If the winch only moves while a button is held at a location from which the entire travel range is visible, different rules would apply.

Comment: @supercat, ASME A17.1 has different requirements for hand-operated, power-operated, and automatic-operation dumbwaiters, and this is in violation of all of them.  (It might also be classified as a "material hoist", in which case it's *still* in violation.)

Comment: @Mark: What are the requirements for a material hoist, and what would be the failings here?  While there's probably room for improvement, I don't think this device should pose any particular hazard to people who don't climb into it, and who only operate it when everybody is clear of it.

Comment: @supercat, the requirements for a material hoist are approximately 300 pages long.  Just to give one failing: "7.5.1.2.2 Each door or gate shall be equipped with a contact that will prevent operation of the driving machine, unless the door or gate panel(s) is in the closed position as defined in 2.14.4.11."

Comment: @Mark: What kinds of equipment are required to meet that specification, and what would distinguish a material hoist from a dumbwaiter?  Interlocked gates would be a logical requirement for parts of a device that are out of line of sight from the controls, or for devices that would be expected to have people enter the space underneath them, but a device like a crane wouldn't be considered unsuitable for use because it has no interlocked safety system to prevent people from walking under a load.

Comment: @Mark: The device could probably use some safety improvements, even if it's only used for raising and lowering goods which are being brought in and trash which is being taken out, but a device which is only being used for such purposes shouldn't be subject to the same requirements as one which will be relied upon to support the weight of workers who are loading and unloading it.

Answer (score 15):

## There's arguably no way to make this safe

There's two bits for this: making it safe enough for an insurance company, which you can't do, because you aren't a licenced engineer, designing from a list of pre tested and approved systems.

But there's also making it safe from your perspective - i.e, turning this into less of a deathtrap. I'd argue this can't be done without a rebuild, either.

My big worry is that the elevator car sticks and slips somewhere. It gets caught on the platform, the cable spools a little, and it drops a little way. The winch that is fine under just a standard load suddenly has the job of bringing an elevator car to a near instantaneous stop.

This is generally something you want to avoid doing in physics. It exposes every bit of the system to a multiple of the regular force on it. None of this system looks designed to handle multiple times the regular weight of the elevator + passenger.

The best case scenario is that the lift cable snaps and the passenger and elevator falls

The worst case is that a chunk of the lift structure collapses too, crushing the passenger under the wreckage, and possibly bringing with it some deck supports.

Winches with steel cables are dangerous enough, even without a deadly lift on them.

That's before, even, you get to backup mechanisms, which are another big design ask.

Then there's interlocks. Nothing, currently, stops someone climbing in underneath it while it is descending. There's a door stopping you going in while the elevator isn't there, but that can just be opened, leaving you to plummet down a lift shaft.

Comment: I can think of a few modifications that could be done to make this a safe(r) dumb waiter.  Shorten the car so it would be difficult for a human to fit inside.  Replace the lower 36 inches or so of the doors with a solid panel, this makes it difficult for children to climb in and puts it about countertop height.  Add lockout switches on the now much smaller doors so the dumbwaiter will not move if either door is open.  Perhaps some other bits could be added but with a minimal amount of parts and labor it should be safe and remain functional.

Comment: Making it "not a deathtrap" is certainly a major project, but I'd say far from impossible. For example, one could start by installing a second winch in parallel with the first one (each of them rated to carry the whole load with a huge factor of safety, as in real lifts). Put them on load cells measuring the instantaneous force on the rope, add a bit of electronics that shuts the whole thing down if there is any sort of significant imbalance (that takes care of either cable, winch, or the car getting stuck or broken). As for interlocks, that's again a bit of electronics + electric doorlocks.

Comment: @TooTea I feel like that would be reinventing the history of the elevator, hoping to avoid every time in the past that someone made a mistake that cost lives.

Comment: @WayneConrad As I said, it is a major project. But all it needs is to be safe. It does not need to be fast, energy-efficient, cheap to build, or reliable (as in "working most of the time"). Nobody cares if it frequently refuses to move because something is not right, making it fail safe is the only goal. That simplifies the engineering a whole lot. And after all, it's just 18 feet, not twelve floors. Even with zero engineering, you could probably just throw two (or four) mattresses under it and already have a decent chance of surviving a fall.

Answer (score 7):

When I built my house, I put an elevator in between the garage and the attic to haul stuff (mostly Christmas decorations) up and down so my wife and I didn't have to drag them up and down stairs. It is a great addition. It is not unlike your elevator, in that it is designed to lift things (not people) and can fail in a number of ways - all of which should not be fatal to those loading and unloading it. Like you, I would not recommend anyone ride in it. Your current elevator is a long way from being safe enough for public transportation (for all the reasons folks have listed) but I don't know what kind of family situation you may be facing that might require you to trade off your family's safety versus getting affordable, stair-free access to an upper floor. I would advise (like the others) that you avoid using it at all for human transportation - there are just so many things that could go wrong and it would take so much to fix all of them. But I also don't want you leaving this forum without any useful advice and doing your best to fix it up because it is worth the risk to your family for reasons we may not understand. So my advice is think about what could go wrong that would be a major issue to you and address those. Lawsuits from non-family members and pinched fingers from doors are probably not what you should focus on. I see a real need for a fully redundant lift system at a minimum and certainly testing that it can actually carry the load prescribed under stressful conditions (including failure of one of the lift systems). And probably retesting it yearly to ensure weather didn't degrade any components. I am also really curious about what would happen if it got stuck between floors with someone on it - either due to a power loss or the rails getting jammed. How would you get them down? And finally, could you live with yourself if you or another family member was critically injured? So again, my advice is don't do it, but if you feel you need to press ahead anyway, please think through the failures and the consequences as best as you can to meet your particular family's needs. And to keep non-family members safe, I would keep the carrier at ground level and flip the circuit breaker so no one can activate it in your absence.

Comment: The location, circumstances and construction matter a lot!  You don't have to worry about people hooking themselves to your garage attic winch as a lazy way of going up there.  Because there's nothing up there for them, and it is clearly a winch even if you have a little platform attached.  If you build a little cabin, put doors on it and leave it permanently attached to the winch, and put a jacuzzi in the garage attic THEN you are entering the territory of OP's lift.

Answer (score 5):

The aspect of elevators that permitted widespread use is the braking mechanism. Trusting one's health to a repurposed winch without a backup seems risky, at best.

If you're determined to make use of this device for moving humans, a secondary support system should be created. On the expensive side of things, I envision a series of nested cylinders containing hydraulic fluid. As the chamber descends, the fluid is pushed into a reservoir through a flow regulating valve. This would mean that a cable break would turn the free falling chamber into a carefully controlled descent.

Alternatively, a cable of similar strength as the winch wrapped around a capstan which is in turn attached to an unsightly large air-paddle would accomplish the same thing at a lower cost. Provision would have to be made to reel in the cable as the chamber ascends as well as allowing it to spool out on the descent. The air-paddle would only come into play if the primary lift cable breaks.

Based on the comments, I could have phrased the device in a different manner. There are exercise machines that drive what amounts to a large fan. If one pictures a paddle driven riverboat, but removes it from the water, it will reach a limiting speed based on friction with the air, as well as moving masses of air.

The comments also reference magnetic control devices commonly used in exercise machines.

A search for controlled descent devices does not return any references to air-paddle control. The idea appeared in a movie from the last century in which jewel thieves jumped from a building attached to a cable on a capstan with an air-paddle descent control. The cable snagged leaving one of the suspects suspended until authorities began winching him up. My suggestion may be as impractical as the idea of converting this to a human-rated lift.

Other aspects mentioned in the comments are valid and should not be overlooked.

'tis a bit of an unusual objective, but I have been considered a risk taker.

Comment: This really is fascinating as a diy thought experiment, but I’d encourage the questioner to consider the liability that comes with any plan.

Comment: More power to you for being a risk taker, but the fundamental issue is not "Do you feel lucky today?", instead it's your insurance company saying "Claim denied" when someone injures themselves during operation of this disaster.  This would result in you being personally sued out the wazoo for all you have.

Comment: Absolutely correct on the fact that a passive braking mechanism is essential.  Not sure about this 'air-paddle' idea though.

Comment: @JimmyJames, I  find air paddles and magnetic brakes  trustworthy as they dont rely on electricity.

Comment: @RohitGupta It might help if I knew what an air paddle was exactly.  A search on the term didn't help.

Comment: @RohitGupta I thought at least one solution for an elevator braking system was centripetal in its design.  Essentially, if the wheel started spinning fast in the down direction, it would throw out wedges that would lock and stop all movement.  The word 'control' is suspect to me here, but I might be reading into it.

Comment: Some climbing walls have a device called an "auto-belay", that take the place of a human belayer.   If the climber falls, the thing only lets the rope out at a slow pace.   Fairly sure it's some kind of centrifugal mechanism inside the thing.   Of course, none of those would be designed for the kind of weight we're talking about here.

Comment: Safely stopping a falling elevator is a solved problem.  None of the methods you describe is used; rather, an overspeed detector causes brakes to clamp on to the elevator's guide rails, bringing the elevator to a stop.  Any safe elevator also has a shock absorber at the bottom, in case the cable breaks while the elevator is near the bottom of the shaft.

Comment: @Mark In fact one of the methods I described (ok, alluded to) IS used in a real elevator.  As I said in 2nd paragraph of OP " I don't think it'd be possible to install a braking mechanism, like the one on a real elevator."

Comment: The problem with an air paddle (@JimmyJames - think of a very inefficient fan - I've built one on a small scale to stop a spool of light wire spinning too much when I stopped pulling the wire at several metres/second) arrangement in this thought experiment is that it's good for limiting the top speed, but not for stopping.  The drag force scales with the square of the velocity.  You'd also need to gear up the air paddle so it spins fast enough to do much at all.  And they do a fair impression of an air raid siren if enclosed in a way that maximises drag.

Comment: Note that a *water* paddle arrangement (higher drag in a heavier more viscous fluid) was used by James Joule among other to [demonstrate the relationship between heat and mechanical work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat#Priority), proving that heat is a form of energy (getting on for 200 years ago).

Comment: @ChrisH, if you've ever examined an air-raid siren, you'll know that's because that's exactly how they are made!

Comment: @Mark, a failsafe doesn't normally have an "overspeed detector".  Rather the cable tension releases the brake, allowing movement only when the car is properly supported.

Comment: @TobySpeight exactly.  I've had a go with a hand-cranked version, and effectively built something similar out of Lego attached to a 20000RPM motor (though the goal was to detect Doppler shift in ultrasound reflected off the paddles)

Comment: Safety regulations and modern elevator designs are written in blood; unless you have a lot of blood to spill you just go with whatever the real elevator design companies are doing because they're doing it for a reason. And they know how to do those designs and you don't. Yes, thought experiments and even real experiments with cargo are encouraged - just not putting humans in them.